# PowerShell, using a function to invoke a switch in a script

Tags: powershell, function, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a simple logging script to save todo items to a log file that I can quickly reference, I save the following as `~\mytodo.ps1`

```
$input = $args
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"

switch ($input[0]) {
    "doing" {
        $input = $input[1..($input.Length - 1)]
        Add-Content -Path ~/log.txt -Value "$(Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy") $input"
        Write-Host "`"$input`" Written to log"
    }
    "today" {
        Select-String -Path ~/log.txt -Pattern $date
    }
    "yesterday" {
        $yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        Select-String -Path ~/log.txt -Pattern $yesterday
    }
    "todo" {
        $input = $input[1..($input.Length - 1)]
        if ($input -eq "") {
            Get-Content ~/todo.log
        } else {
            Add-Content -Path ~/todo.log -Value "$date $input"
        }
    }
}
```

I find that I can invoke these switches on the console as follows:

```
& $HOME/mytodo.ps1 doing "add note to the log"
```

So I then setup functions in my profile to invoke the switches, thinking these should work

```
function doing { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 doing $args }
function today { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 today $args }
function yesterday { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 yesterday $args }
function todo { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 todo $args }
```

However, the functions seem to treat the input arguments as objects:
`doing 123`, or `doing "123"` both produce the following:

```
"System.Object[]" Written to log
```

How can I make each function invoke the switch in the script without the input string being treated as a string?

Comment: don't use `$input` as a variable name. it is an automatic variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The following is incidental to your problem, but worth noting:

  - **Avoid use of the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) for custom purposes.**
- In order **to *relay* the positional arguments reflected in the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) between PowerShell commands, you must use [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)**, i.e. **`@args`**, which ensures that the arguments are passed on *individually* (and again collected in `$args` by the target command).

  - *Without* splatting, i.e. when using `$args` as an argument, the collected original arguments are passed *as a single, array-valued* argument, which results in the *target* command's `$args` array having a *single* element that is an *array* - this is what you saw.
  - As an aside: This does *not* happen when invoking *external programs*, in which case splatting is *implicitly* applied (that is, `foo.exe $args` is in essence the same as `foo.exe @args`).

```bash
# Note the use of @args instead of $args
function doing { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 doing @args }
function today { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 today @args }
function yesterday { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 yesterday @args }
function todo { & $HOME/mytodo.ps1 todo @args }
```

Answer (score 3):

2 things you'll want to change:

1. Avoid assignment to the automatic variable `$input`
2. Use explicit string operators (like `-join`) for constructing the output string

```
# shift action from args
$action,$info = $args

$date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"

switch ($action) {
    "doing" {
        $logline = @($date;$info) -join ' '
        Add-Content -Path ~/log.txt -Value $logline
        Write-Host "`"$logline`" Written to log"
    }
    "today" {
        Select-String -Path ~/log.txt -Pattern $date
    }
    "yesterday" {
        $yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        Select-String -Path ~/log.txt -Pattern $yesterday
    }
    "todo" {
        if (@($info).Count -eq 0) {
            Get-Content ~/todo.log
        } else {
            $logline = @($date;$info) -join ' '
            Add-Content -Path ~/todo.log -Value $logline
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, [follow mklement0's splatting suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77826827/712649) when writing the invoking functions, and it should work as expected

Comment: Thanks for some cleaner methods here though I'm not following why you have `$action` and `$info` both from `$args`. Would you not want to do `$action[0]` in case a component in `$args` also contains a keyword later in the string being input?